# How to save a custom text style?

Tags: ms-word

I have a particular body and title text styles (font, size, color, weight, spacing) that I want to reuse throughout a doc.

At the moment I highlight the text and apply each style (font, color etc) separately for every occurance.

How can I save a custom text style (eg red arial heading) to reuse throughout a doc and possibly for future documents?

Comment: Aren't You asking a programming question, are you asking [how to customize the style in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563)?